# Windows software to send SMS via ActiveSync through a Windows Mobile Phone

Tags: windows-7, windows, sms

I've got an HTC Dopod 810 phone which runs Windows Mobile 5.0.

I want to be able to send SMS messages from a Windows PC (XP and 7) from the phone while connected via the USB port. I am using ActiveSync to synchronize the phone with Outlook 2003 and 2007 (two different machines).

What is the best software for this? It would be useful to differentiate between free and paid for products as I'd be happy to pay for something if it was really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use jeyo mobile extender http://www.jeyo.com/extender.asp
It does not specifically state windows 7 but works for me without problems and also archives sms into outlook folder.
when installing note the readme file that states "create a firewall exception for Extender on port 9035" 
There is a free trial and then only costs $19.95

Suggest you give it a try.

Comment: Looks good. Do you know what the difference is between Jeyo Mobile Extender and Jeyo Mobile Companion is? I've been reading the site but am struggling to differentiate between the two. Guess I should just give bot a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a piece of software I have used in the past called [TrueConnect](http://www.raspberrysoftware.com/trueconnect.htm) which includes integration that allows you to send and receive SMS messages from Outlook on the host, when the phone is connected.

There is a 14 day trial, but, at time of writing, it only costs 30 USD for the full thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this software, its free:

http://www.dnisoftware.co.uk/content/Free+Software.aspx

Comment: I tried this but get the following Exception when I try to run it on a Windows 7 64 bit system. I did try it with Admin priviledges as well.
"OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPIException: Error 2: Cannot Create Process"

Comment: I believe it needs to run in 32 bit compatibility mode because the rapi dll hasnt been ported to the 64 bit environment yet.

Comment: Greate bit of software, worked perfectly :D